# Internal Server Error returned when uploading to OneDrive

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to upload a file to OneDrive using the MS Graph API, but today I have started to receive an error back when trying to upload.

The error is being thrown on this line:

```
var uploadSession = await graphClient.Users[userId].Drive.Items[itemId].ItemWithPath(fileName).CreateUploadSession().Request().PostAsync();
```

The error message I am getting back is simply 'InternalServerError' with the message 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'.  The code I have has been working happily in production for a year, but today has suddenly started throwing this exception.

I have tried debugging local, but do not get any more information and I have updated the nuget packages to the latest version, but still get the same error.

Comment: I should also say, that the graphClient is successfully authenticated.  Just prior to this line, I use it to access user info and folders that the user currently has on OneDrive.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was caused by a Microsoft update, which has now been resolved.  Github issue [646](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/646)